# How to use identity 2.2 and don't use ILookupNormalizer on ApplicationUserManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-3.0

how can I remove any ILookupNormalizer injection in identity core3 preview4?

I use identity 2.2 and can't use ILookupNormalizer on ApplicationUserManager.
My contracture ApplicationUserManager :

```
public ApplicationUserManager(
            IApplicationUserStore store,
            IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
            IPasswordHasher<TblUsers> passwordHasher,
            IEnumerable<IUserValidator<TblUsers>> userValidators,
            IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<TblUsers>> passwordValidators,
            ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
            IdentityErrorDescriber errors,
            IServiceProvider services,
            ILogger<ApplicationUserManager> logger,
            IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
            IUsedPasswordsService usedPasswordsService)
            : base((UserStore<TblUsers, TblOrganizationChart, AbfaContext, int, TblUserClaim, TblUserOrganizationChart, TblUserLogin, TblUserToken, TblRoleClaim>)store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
```

When I add ILookupNormalizer on AddCustomServices, I have this error:

> Method 'NormalizeName' in type 'Project.Core.Identity.CS.CustomNormalizers' from assembly 'Project.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

after remove "services.AddScoped();" I have this error:

> 'Method 'NormalizeKey' in type 'Project.Core.Identity.ApplicationUserManager' from assembly 'Project.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.'

I don't need to use Normalizer.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signature of `ILookupNormalizer` in Identity core 3x [is different](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/ILookupNormalizer.cs) than the 2x. If you want to continue using your old project and you don't want to upgrade it yet (according to the title of your question), just lock the framework version of your solution by using a [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) file. First run the `dotnet --list-sdks` command to see which versions are installed. Then create a new one in the root of your solution using `dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 2.2.106` command.

```
dotnet --list-sdks
dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 2.2.106
```

Comment: I use this command and I have this error:
`'Method 'NormalizeKey' in type 'Project.Core.Identity.ApplicationUserManager' from assembly 'Project.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.'`
All of my nuget was update.

Comment: When you lock your sdk version, you should use the old signature of the `ILookupNormalizer` which has `string Normalize(string key);` in it

Comment: I do this before but have that error again. 
Also, I use this code: `public interface IUserNameLookupNormalizer : ILookupNormalizer {}
public interface IEmailLookupNormalizer : ILookupNormalizer {}` 
but no correct.

Comment: If you have the same error `Method 'NormalizeName' does not have an implementation` again, it means you are still using the new SDK `3x`. Make sure your `global.json` file has a 2x version in it, also check out your `dependencies`. All of them should point to 2x version. Also delete all of the `bin` and `obj` folders too to remove all of the inconsistencies. Now run `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` again.

Comment: The last version of Identity is 2.2.
Where can I download 3.x version?

Comment: It's part of the SDK or your `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` dependency located at `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192562/discussion-between-lpln-and-vahidn).